# Why is my section tag not post to my other page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a section tag that its value get updated based on what the user clicks a package in `page1.php`. i.e nothing selected, the section tag with have nothing in it, the user selects package 1 the section tag now because package 1. but when I use php to `POST` it and check if it is set it is not is there a reason for this?

I want the `POST_['foodchoice']` to be set so that I can have a section in `page2.php` where I can summarize what packages a user have selected.

Sort of like a shopping cart functionality but with no database, quantity selections etc.
Please advise why. Thanks

**page1.php**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">


function changemyButton() 
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("button3");
  if (elem.value == "Un-Select Package") 
    elem.value = "Select This Package";
  else if( elem.value == "Package Selected!" ) {
      elem.value = "Select This Package";
       elem.style.background = "#003e7e";
       document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = '';

  } else {
    elem.value = "Package Selected!";
    elem.style.background = "green";
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = '1x The Share Collection';
  }



}
</script>

<h1 id="logo">      Breakfast Menu Options          </h1></section> 

<hr>

</br>
 <center>


<form action="homePage.php" method="post" onsubmit="">
<center>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">             </script>
 <div class= "breakfast">
<u><h2>The Share Collection</h2></u>
</br>
<img src= "\images\Breakfast\breakfast1.jpg" class="funky">
 </br>
 </br>
 <dl>
 <dd>Mini jar of housemade granola: vanilla yoghurt, fresh fruit (v) (6)</dd>
 <dd>Goat cheese, cherry tomato &amp; basil, mushroom tart (v) (8)</dd>


<dd>Mini slider jamon serrano, fig jam, rocket, brie &amp; black pepper (8) </dd>
 <dd>Chef's mini sweet muffin (v) (8)</dd>
 <dd>Bowl of strawberries &amp; grapes (v) (1)</dd>
 </dl>
 </br>
 <input type='button' value='Select This Package' id='button3' onclick="changemyButton()">
<hr>
   <section id="myform">    
    <h1 id="logo">Total Ordered</h1></section>
<hr>
</br>
<section id ="selection" name="foodchoice"></section>



<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>



<input type="button" id="button4" value="Submit Your Selection" name="submit" onclick="window.location='homePage.php';" >
</div>



    </center>
    </form>


    </div>
    </div>
```

**Page 2.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );


if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) {

header("Location: openingPage.php");

exit();

}

if (isset($_POST['foodchoice'])) 
{
   echo "yay!";
}

  if (!isset($_POST['foodchoice']))

  {

echo "nay!";

  }


?>
```

Then within my html body I will have:

```
<div id ="packageselected">

<?php  echo $_POST['foodchoice'];   ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking. `<section>` is not a form control. Only form controls get submitted. `name` is only valid on form controls also

Comment: @charlietfl So what could I use for form control in this instance? I don't want a text box or a dropdown I just want text being passed what would you suggest?

Comment: Your last line has underscore in wrong place `$POST_['foodchoice']` should be `$_POST['foodchoice']`

Comment: `name="submit" onclick="window.location='homePage.php';"` will NOT submit your form.

Comment: You are right sorry I added the `div` just to explain better what I wanted to achieve. I have updated it. Thanks

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I know but my `action="homepage.php"` does nothing so had to find a way to re-direct the page to see if `$_POST['foodchoice']` was being set. Sorry I am a beginner in web development.